# How to write a For loop for 2*3 subplots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have written this long piece of code to make a subplot like below
[subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXDMA.png)

My code is like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15, 8), sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=4)
Asia_data=df[df.Region=='Asia']
Africa_data=df[df.Region=='Africa']
Europe_data=df[df.Region=='Europe']
ME_data=df[df.Region=='Middle East']
Oceania_data=df[df.Region=='Oceania']
America_data=df[df.Region=='The Americas']

sns.histplot(ax=axes[0,0], data=Africa_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[0,1], data=Asia_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[0,2], data=Europe_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1,0], data=ME_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1,1], data=Oceania_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1,2], data=America_data,x="Life Expectancy Female", 
kde=True,stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
axes[0,0].set_title('Africa')
axes[0,1].set_title('Asia')
axes[0,2].set_title('Europe')
axes[1,0].set_title('Middle East')
axes[1,1].set_title('Oceania')
axes[1,2].set_title('The Americas')
fig.suptitle('Histogram and KDE of Life Exppectancy of Wemon', fontsize=15)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
```

How could I improve this code and put all these steps into a For loop?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
regions = ['Asia', 'Africa', 'Europe', 
           'Middle East', 'Oceania', 'The Americas']

for ax, region in zip(axes.flat, regions):
    sns.histplot(ax=ax, data=df[df.Region == region],
                 x="Life Expectancy Female", kde=True, 
                 stat='probability').set(xlabel=None)
    ax.set_title(region)
```

Or consider using [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html).